# Is it possible to read a parameter at runtime from inside Azure Function Linked Service in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I need to dynamically call an Azure Function from inside my ADF pipeline.

Currently i'm able to parameterize the functionName through the Azure Function Activity, but i'm not able to parameterize nor the functionKey nor the URL.

The URL is no problem since I can store all the functions below the same URL but the functionKey is really a must for this.

Do you now any option to do that?

What I've tried

Parameter inside the json as with DataStoreLinkedServices:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureFunction",
        "annotations": [],
        "parameters": {
            "functionSecret": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "typeProperties": {
            "functionAppUrl": "https://<myurl>.azurewebsites.net",
            "functionKey": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "KeyVaultLinkedService",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "@{linkedService().functionSecret}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ErrorMsg:

```
"code":"BadRequest","message":"No value provided for Parameter 'functionSecret'"
```

Is there a way to achieve this? It seems not obvious, and I didn't found anything surfing the web. The most similar was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076004/setting-a-linked-service-parameter-at-runtime-in-a-data-factory-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer myself just in case someone have the same problem, what we do to manage this was parameterize the needed information from the pipeline itself.

So we have a pipeline that just call a generic Azure Function. In the caller pipeline, there is a process to obtain the desired parameters from the KeyVault and pass them to the AF pipeline.

The LS remain as follows:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureFunction",
        "typeProperties": {
            "functionAppUrl": "https://@{linkedService().functionAppUrl}.azurewebsites.net",
            "functionKey": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "KeyVaultLinkedService",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "@{linkedService().functionKey}"
            }
        },
        "parameters": {
            "functionAppUrl": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "@pipeline().parameters.functionAppUrl"
            },
            "functionKey": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "@pipeline().parameters.functionKey"
            }
        }
    }
}
```